# How do I switch dependency injection bindings at startup based on a configuration file?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

How do I change my injected dependencies at runtime? I have a provider that performs a service and it will change from time to time. It won't change every time the application runs and I don't expect it change the dependencies on-the-fly while the application is running. I'd like to place my configuration in a file so we don't need to build & deploy when a dependency changes, not to mention the time required to build & deploy.

How do I move my bindings to an external configuration file (XML or JSON)? Can I still leave most bindings in startup.cs but supplement them with the external config file?

Comment: The easiest way would be an `if` where you fill your `ServiceCollection` and branch on something from your current configuration file. Do you need something more complex?

Comment: You cannot entirely escape have to rebuild and redeploy, unless you do something nasty like dynamically load assemblies via reflection. Otherwise, if you add a new dependency, you'll also have to build and redeploy so that your compiled app code has that reference.